# Self-energy of a uniformly charged, non-conducting sphere, using energy density formula

Tags: electromagnetism, potential-energy

I am trying to derive the formula for the self-energy of a non-conducting sphere. I know it to be $$E = \frac{3Q^2}{40\pi\epsilon_0 R}$$

I am trying to use the energy density formula for it which is 
$$ \frac{dU}{dV} = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0 E^2$$

My method was to find the general formula for the $E$-Field inside the non-conducting sphere, which is $$ E = \frac{Qr}{4\pi\epsilon_0R}$$
Then using that, and setting $dV=4\pi r^2dr$, then solving for U using the energy density formula, by integrating between 0 and R (the radius of the sphere). However, in doing this, I am out by a factor of 3, and cant figure out why.
Any ideas? Or have I just messed up somewhere, I have looked *extensively* through my written work and everything seems sound, so I suspect the issue is with my physical intuition.

Comment: You must surely add the energy that is stored in the empty space surrounding the sphere. Incidentally you need to say that the charge density is the same throughout the sphere. And your equation for electric field, , inside the sphere needs $R^3$, not , on the bottom.

Comment: I've just carried out the calculation and get twice the answer you quoted for $U$. Well, I suppose a factor of 2 isn't as badly out as a factor of 3. If you're interested I'll give my working.

Comment: I agree with your calculation of the energy stored inside the sphere (one third of your quoted formula for the total $U$).

Answer (score 7):

The field outside the sphere is the usual Coulomb expression:

$$E_{out} = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{Q}{r^2}$$

the field inside is linear and agrees with the outside field at $r=R$ so must be:

$$E_{in} = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{Qr}{R^3}$$

Thus the energy densities are:

$$u_{out} = \frac{Q^2}{32\pi^2\epsilon_0} \frac{1}{r^4}$$

$$u_{in} = \frac{Q^2}{32\pi^2\epsilon_0} \frac{r^2}{R^6}$$

We integrate $V = 4\pi \left( \int_0^R u_{in}r^2dr + \int_R^\infty u_{out}r^2dr\right)$ which gives:

$$V = \frac{Q^2}{8\pi\epsilon_0 R} \left(\frac{1}{5} + 1 \right) = \frac{3}{5} \frac{Q^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0 R}$$.

This last expression is correct even though it disagrees with what the OP thought they were aiming for by a factor of 2.

Comment: Brilliant, thankyou. Never thought to consider going from R to infinity.