# How to compute the self-energy of a sphere? Electrostatics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, potential-energy

Not just the formula, how to derive it as well, im lost in this topic any help would be great.

Comment: check out Griffiths

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Self-energy of a uniformly charged, non-conducting sphere, using energy density formula](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/538094/self-energy-of-a-uniformly-charged-non-conducting-sphere-using-energy-density)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can evaluate the electric energy of a sphere $U_{el}$ in this way:
first consider that the charge is $Q=\rho \frac{4}{3}\pi R^3$.

Let's start from the general formula: $$U_{el}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{Volume}VdQ$$
Then, using Gauss'Law you can calculate the electric potential of the sphere for radiuses smaller then the radius of the sphere: $$V(r<R)=\frac{\rho}{3\epsilon_0}\frac{3R^2-r^2}{2}=\frac{Q}{8\pi \epsilon_0}\Big(3-\frac{r^2}{R^2}\Big)$$
You know that the infinitesimal charge is $dQ=\rho \cdot 4\pi r^2\cdot dr$ using the infinitesimal volume of the sphere.
So you have: $$U_{el}=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^R \frac{Q}{8\pi \epsilon_0}\Big(3-\frac{r^2}{R^2}\Big)\rho \cdot 4\pi r^2\cdot dr$$ $$U_{el}=\frac{Q\rho}{4\epsilon_0R^3}\Big[3R^2\cdot \Big(\frac{r^3}{3}\Big)^R_0-\Big(\frac{r^5}{5}\Big)^R_0\Big]$$ $$U_{el}=\frac{Q\rho}{4\epsilon_0R^3}\cdot \frac{4}{5}R^5=\frac{3Q^2}{20\pi \epsilon_0R}$$
This is the internal electric energy of your sphere.